# How to record phone calls in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to record Phone calls in objective c, is there any library available to to record phone call.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @JonRose how to use that code to record the calls.

Comment: With private APIs / a jailbroken phone it is possible. Apart from that it seems all apps that "record" a conversation actually add another participant to the call and let that robo participant of their own record the call. From a privacy and legal standpoint that is quite questionable and from a technical standpoint at least complex.

Comment: Without jailbroken / APIs do we have any chance to implement @luk2302

Comment: Any update on this @luk2302? can i do this without jailbraking ?